# C# Read in a bmp image as binary

Tags: c#

I have no idea how to read an image in as a binary image. I have being using the following lines however it keeps reading in null.

```
FileStream inf = new FileStream(name.ToString(), FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.ReadWrite);
BinaryReader data = new BinaryReader(inf);
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? Just get the bytes of the file? For that, [File.ReadAllBytes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.readallbytes%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is the fastest way to get them into a byte array. If you need the bytes as a stream, looks like you've already got that.

Answer (score 1):

It really depends on what you want to do.  For example, if you want to read in a .bmp file and display it in a PictureBox, you can do something like the following:

(assumes there's a PictureBox named pictureBox1)

```
        Stream bmpStream = null;
        var ofd1 = new OpenFileDialog();
        if(ofd1.ShowDialog()==DialogResult.OK)
        {
            try
            {
                bmpStream = ofd1.OpenFile();
                if(bmpStream != null)
                {
                    using (bmpStream)
                    {
                        pictureBox1.Image = new Bitmap(bmpStream);
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Error:  could not read file. " + ex.Message);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

why don't you take a look on this topic [How to open image in C# and convert to binary](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/51505b86-7b4c-4d11-8295-8002d36cd5a3/how-to-open-image-in-c-and-convert-to-binary-and-show-it-on-the-form?forum=csharpgeneral),it seems to be like what you're asking for, but for image in black and white, however there are some methods that can help you. I hope you find this helpful or at least that lead you in the right direction.

Regards